# Refactor whereHas to use via global scopes in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I've 2 models, `CoreChallenge` and `Challenge`. Below are relations between table.
[image: relation between tables]

I want to fetch `Challenges` which has `core_challenges` active. I tried to do putting global scope in `CoreChallenge` model, but when I'm getting `null` in relationship when `Corechallenge` is `inactive`.

#### I've done it this way

```
$challenges = Challenge::with('core_challenge')->whereHas('core_challenge', function($q){
            $q->where('status', '=', 'active');
        })->get();
```

#### I want to do it using global scopes

Global scope on `CoreChallenge` gives me null, but I want that it's parent (`Challenge`) should not load even, like in `whereHas`. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled to the same approach, but when the table got bigger (core_challenges_table in your scenario), `whereHas` ended up being very slow (around 1min response time).

So I used a solution like this:

```
$ids = CoreChallenge::where('status', 'active')->pluck('id');

$challenges = Challenge::with('core_challenges')
                        ->whereIn('core_challenge_id', $ids)
                        ->get();
```

With this approach, my query reduced to 600~ms from 1min.

Which can be translated to Model scopes

```
class Challenge {

   public function scopeActive($query) {
       $activeIds = CoreChallenge::where('status', 'active')->pluck('id');

       return $query->whereIn('core_challenge_id', $ids);
   }
}

Challenge::with('core_challenges')->active()->get();
```